# Why do we need total selectivity?

Tags: circuit-breaker

If a fault happens in DR3 that makes Ideltan bigger than 30mA, the flow of current will stop. What's the need for the other circuit breakers?

[image]

Comment: What's the context here? What do these individual lines represent? Is it a 3-phase system?

Comment: Are those breakers or GFCIs? The current values (down to 30mA) suggests the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You don't understand the diagram.

Partly because it is badly made. See how there are lines going off to the left and right? Why did they draw those?

See how the load lines zigzag back and forth for no reason whatsoever?   Why are they not lined up?

It's because the artist was lazy. A better artist would have drawn it more like this.

[image]

Now you can see what your artist was trying to convey - there are many other panels and many other loads.

Now you can see the value of selective coordination - setting it up so a local trip stays as local as possible, and doesn't take out countless other users.